# 405 Method Not Allowed wehn doing HTTP POST to ASp .Net Core 2.2 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-code-405

I'm creating an ASP .Net Core 2.2 Web API, and am implementing a controller action which will be invoked via a POST. However, when I run it in Debug mode in Visual Studio 2017, and I call the endpoint using Postman, I get a **405 Method Not Allowed**

I specified that I am doing this in debug mode in VS because I've seen a couple of posts online where people are getting this issue when deploying, and having to remove WebDAV from IIS or adding this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

to their config.web

However, seeing as I am running from VS, it is using IIS Express, and there is no web.config file.

I haven't yet tried to publish the API, as it's not even working locally on my machine, so it feels wrong to publish something that's broken.

**EDIT:**

So my controller looks like this:

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{

    public TestController()
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    private void Post()
    {
        Console.Write("TEST");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your code? There's nothing wrong with POST, all sites use it unless they are read-only. Even the tutorials wouldn't work if forms couldn't POST to the server

Comment: Besides, ASP.NET Core *doesn't* use `web.config` unless it's hosted on IIS. The default servier is [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: That's right, there is no web.config until you publish. That's why I can't even try the suggestion I've seen online about adding those lines to the web.config file. Regarding the code sample, well, there's not much to post...currently I have a controller with just one simple, parameterless action, which has "Console.Write("TEST"); in its body and nothing else. And it has the [HttpPost] decoration. If I change it to a [HttpGet] decoration, and do a GET request from Postman, then it works.

Comment: You don't *need* a web.config during debugging. Even after publishing it doesn't mean you need one. Kestrel doesn't need it. Post the code.

Comment: `just one simple, parameterless action` a POST without a body? How did you call it?

Comment: I've edited my original question to show the controller code

Comment: Post a reproducible example that actually reproduces the problem. POST works. If it didn't, a *lot* of developers would have noticed. I would too, since I have a few ASP.NET Core Web API projects that use POST. One of them even uses file uploads. I can use it in a form just fine. I can use it with `fetch` too

Comment: It did have a parameter, but I removed it for testing to keep things as simple as possible.. It doesn't work however, with or without a parameter...

Comment: Yes of course POST works... it's just not working in this project for some reason... I've used it in other projects successfully.. But it's fine, thanks. I will try and figure it out.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and _the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself_. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: why is your post method `private` ?

Comment: LGSon, I'm not sure what the shortest code necessary to reproduce it would be... It all depends where the problem lies. If it's in my Startup.cs or my Program.cs then that would probably have to be included too. But ok, I'll try edit my question to make it better. I just thought perhaps someone had a similar issue and they might know what the solution is.

Comment: Thank you so much noobed! That's it - I made my action method private instead of public! Well spotted! Thank you so much!

Comment: I changed to public, but still same error

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by the keen-eyed *noobed*, my problem was that my controller action was **private** and not **public**. Thanks again noobed.

Comment: Nooby maybe but I ran into just the same issue!